# Jackson doesn't serialize nested classes in Spring

Tags: spring, rest, jackson

I have an implementation of a REST front-end UI and a Spring JPA based backend. 
In it, I have a class like this:

```
public class TaskInfo {

    // 4 fields

    private Parent parentList;

    // 3 fields

    // Getters and Setters

}

class Parent {

    // Parent class code
}
```

When I try to take a `Response`, I find that in place of `Parent`, I get a `null` value. Why is this `Parent` object not getting serialized? Is there a workaround to this? Or should I just include the fields of `Parent` in this class directly?

**Edit**: I'm using Jackson for serialization.

Comment: Are you using gson? or jackson?. Can you update the question with it?

Comment: Maybe because your class has a package visibility ? @SamuelAlexander, relevant question !

Comment: @SamuelAlexander Jackson. Added that in question.

Comment: I just did a sample and it works perfectly with jackson

Comment: Are you sure, there is a value set to parentList?

Comment: @ArneBurmeister It's actually a one-many relationship, so in order to avoid a circular reference, I used a separate Parent class. And yes, `parentList` does have a value. I'm just not getting why a class in a class is not working. I still haven't gotten it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the below works fine. I think this is equivalent to the code present in your question

```
package jackson;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TaskInfo {

    public TaskInfo(String id, Parent parentList) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.parentList = parentList;
    }

    private String id;
    private Parent parentList;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Parent getParentList() {
        return parentList;
    }

    public void setParentList(Parent parentList) {
        this.parentList = parentList;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Parent parent = new Parent("123");
        TaskInfo taskInfo = new TaskInfo("taskID", parent);
        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(taskInfo);

        System.out.println(json);
    }

}

class Parent {

    public Parent(String parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public String getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(String parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    private String parentId;
    // Parent class code
}
```

It prints the following output

> {"id":"taskID","parentList":{"parentId":"123"}}

I used jackson

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't know why I get null. I have traced the problem to this, so this must be the problem. Maybe I forgot a setter somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't serialize because your properties are not public. Make the properties public and it works.

Comment: Properties are not set to public in Java. Methods are.